# Why does my NSURL object is equal to nil? My path is correct

Tags: iphone, nsurl

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%lf,%lf&output=csv&sensor=false&key=swizzlec hops", coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"urlString: %@", urlString); 
NSURL *urlFromURLString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

My log is : http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=53.872874,27.527790&output=csv&sensor=false&key=swizzlec hops

I can copy this url and paste to the browser and its ok, but urlFromURLString = nil. But, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
```

on urlString before passing it to NSURL.

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%lf,%lf&output=csv&sensor=false&key=swizzlec hops", coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding::NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%lf,%lf&output=csv&sensor=false&key=swizzlec hops", coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I don't think you can have spaces in your URL

Comment: yup thats the answer, i was about to write it :)

Comment: @Voloda2 Please see my answer. You need to properly encode your string

Answer (score 0):

This is a better approach:

```
NSString* escapedUrl = [originalUrl   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *urlFromURLString = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrl];
```

Comment: Why is that a better approach? It's only semantically different, the implementation is exactly the same.