# Http Get request issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl

I need to get the data from service `URL`. But I couldn't get it .May be something like whitespaces is preventing it .I couldn't understand how to resolve it.

```
NSString *urlString= [NSString
stringWithFormat:@"http://252.249.193.152/Services/User?q=John&p=Browny&r=City Hospital&s=03/13/2013&t=04:00PM&u=ue1f002d-8c8f-4acba75b-8960a6c33bbt&APIKEY=d80d1db7-10d5-4b45-9212-3c699332f2c9"];
    NSURL *jsonUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

But I get null in array and jsonurl is returning `nil`.

Comment: I'm wondering why a URL to an XML resource is called `jsonUrl`...

Comment: are u sure the url is right? check the url on ur system browser, does it returns any json response..

Comment: That url loads nothing. Have you provided right url here?

Comment: Actually I have changed the url.But it is in this format only.For understanding purpose I wrote this.And when i check it in browser I do get XML response.

Comment: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding  use this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my NSURL object is equal to nil? My path is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505294/why-does-my-nsurl-object-is-equal-to-nil-my-path-is-correct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Check Your `URL` ,  I am Sure that mistake in there , if your `URL` is proper then use following code.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL_STRING"];
NSURL *jsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Ya tried ur code and u r right.Problem was with the spaces in the string .ThanQ